# How to make a name show instead of a number when sending sms through a Gateway?

Tags: anonymous, sms-gateway

this question is a tad more on the technical side, but I hope it can be easilly solved.

You see, my problem here is the following:

I have a Gateway for sending SMS, however, I want those SMS to show a name instead of the number (company/Bank name for instance) like some Banks/providers have over here.

However I can't seem to find any sort of documentation on how to achieve this.
Is there any sort of way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Each SMS gateway has its own unique API.  You need to tell us which SMS gateway service you're using and what programming language you're using to create the SMS messages.

Comment: I believe it's an HG-1600 Gateway, if not it's the 2000 or 3000 models (I have no physical access to it so can't really check)
about language, I think it's WinSpice3 that it's using
(we use a browser interface but will have access to the gateway physically if there's any need to change configurations)

Comment: WinSpice3, as best as I can tell from the Internet, is an electronic circuit simulator.  The SMS software for the HG-1600 Gateway, according to their website is [Diroblue](http://www.dirocom.net/Diroblue.html).  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: ok just got new info on this, the gateway is an HG-1600 but the language implementation is actually C#, any possibility for some assistance?

Comment: Do you have access to the C# software that generates the SMS messages?  If so, then look through the software for where the number is added to the SMS message.